# How to get value of only single column using eloquent model

Tags: php, laravel, collections, eloquent

This is my object

```
{
   "id":1,
   "name":"abc",
   "tech":"PHP"
}
```

now i want to get value of tech using User eloquent model using laravel collection method first
this is my eloquent model query

```
$tech = User::select('tech')->first();
```

but it return data is form of object like this

```
{"tech":"PHP"}
```

i want only value in string formate not in object like it should return "PHP".
can any one help?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`pluck`](https://laravel.com/api/5.7/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.html#method_pluck) function for this.

```
$tech = User::pluck('tech')->first();
```

This will return:

```
"php"
```

Comment: Glad I could help. Consider marking this as the answer to your question so other users might find this solution as well.

Answer (score 0):

Your code

```
$tech = User::select('tech')->first();
```

as you said

> Actually it will returns the object

```
{"tech":"PHP"}
```

try this to get the result the

```
$tech = User::select('tech')->first()->tech;
```

not as

```
$tech = User::select('tech')->first();
```